# IPhone: Integrating Merchant API Payment Processing (Real Goods)

Tags: iphone, credit-card

I've been doing research on an application that will sell real-world goods/services.  After reading the rules we cannot use the 'in-app-purchase' model and must integrate (so it seems) with a 3rd party merchant service for credit card processing.  This is good because apple's fee (30%) is pretty high.

So my question is - have you integrated with a specific merchant payment processor system that worked well with the iphone?

I know paypal has their thing - but i'd rather have the user store their credit card info in the app to make purchases.

Example app:  http://splickit.com/ (someone who is doing this)

your feedback/comments appreciated.

Comment: And users would rather you never see their credit card information for as long as you live. So would I. :)

Comment: Implement Stripe. You can store tokens that can be used to bill a card without violating PCI by actually storing card details.

Answer (score 1):

From [Splick-it's FAQ](http://www.splickit.com/faq/): "Splick-it does not store credit card information on the phone itself. All credit card data is passed through to a secure, PCI-compliant payment gateway, who simply returns a thumbs-up or thumbs-down when a customer attempts to use that card to pay for a Splick-it order."

As [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642626/store-credit-cards-in-app) [people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473337/storing-credit-card-details-in-the-iphone-app) on SO have also noted, storing the card details in an app may open you to problems with [PCI-DSS compliance](http://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pcifaqs.php), which is going to be the main issue when you do anything with card payment.

Might be worth contacting Splick-it to ask them which payment processor they went with.