# Storing Credit Card details in the iPhone App

Tags: iphone, credit-card

We develop iPhone App for sale some things 
We want to help users  buy quickly ("in 1 touch")
I found similar questions but they are all about websites

May you answer - Is this legal to save details of CC (number, name, exp date - without CVC code, which user have to enter on the payment page) inside the App on the device ?
All data stored only inside App

From our side it looks like: 
user save data in his profile and use this info for quick filling of payment form inside our App.
If user loses his device - it's his fault :) or am I wrong?

Comment: think its not a good idea , how ever if you didnt find any way think of md5 or your own for security...

Comment: @kantu Uh, MD5 for credit card numbers would be a) useless and b) stupidly insecure.

Comment: i know duh !! hence i have also told to come up with his own algo

Answer (score 16):

It is legal to store credit card data in your application.  However, your application needs to be PCI compliant.  Read up on this here: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/.  There are hefty fines that VISA/Mastercard can leverage if a fraud breach occurs due to your software, up to hundereds of thousands of dollars per transgression.  This isn't the kind of thing to mess with lightly.

Comment: @llia, do you need any further information from me in order to accept this answer?

Comment: @DJ Quimby   if app will pass the assessment with **PCI Security Standard** will it be approved in iphone  appstore ??

Comment: sorry @gEeKyMiNd I've never done Apple development so I don't know what the Apple Store requires.

Answer (score 3):

DJ Quimby has it right (his answer is in this feed). Once you complete the development of a mobile app that allows for credit card payments you'll need a third party to perform security assessment and determine whether you have satisfactorily met the Payment Card Industry (PCI) payment Application Data Security Standard (PA-DSS) version 1.2 related to the protection of cardholder data. If you're storing the full credit card number and/or expiration date in your app, it will not pass this PCI assessment. Without passing the assessment your app will be rejected by the iTunes app store.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's legal.

No, it's probably not something your merchant bank will be a fan of.

No, it's not a good idea at all.

No, Apple won't approve your app.

Comment: "No, Apple won't approve your app." - Can you provide a link that details this? If it's something that Apple strictly prohibits it would be great to see that in their developer agreement, etc.

Comment: @SomethingOn Apple's rules leave a lot of leeway for them to reject stuff for "holy shit this is a horribly dangerous idea" without that being an explicit guideline.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you plan on developing your own in App payment system. This is forbidden by Apple. You must use the storeKit framework. Apple already stores the credit card info on their side so you have one less problem to think about :)

Comment: in our variant user can save some CC in the profile,
like: Pay by Master *****1111/ Visa ***** 2222